# The word "continuum" and its usage in French (e.g. "la mécanique du continuum")

Tags: usage, mathématiques, latin, science, académique

Google translates

> Mechanics of continua
>
> Continuum Mechanics

as

> Mécanique du continua (faulty as it should be des continua but it is not the point considered here)
>
> Mécanique du continuum

On the other hand, [Cambridge translation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/translate/) and this [service](https://www.translate.com/) gives

> Mécanique des milieux continus

My natif French colleagues suggest that I do not use Google suggestions and proceed with the classic structures

> Mécanique du milieu continu/Mécanique des milieux continus

Indeed a Ngram finds nothing regarding mécanique du continuum and furthermore I have yet to find a single French book to use such terminology.

**Nevertheless, the very term continuum exists in French**. Indeed:

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/continuum/18628?q=continuum#18524

http://cnrtl.fr/definition/continuum

http://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition.php?mot=continuum

https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/continuum/#citation

with the exact connotation of

> Continuum espace-temps.
>
> Les concepts de continuum
> espace-temps, d'énergie, de force, de masse, d'entropie.

Le Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/continuum)) gives:

> MATH., PHILOS. Espace qui n'est pas interrompu (cf. continu II) :
> Toutes les géométries que j'envisageais avaient ainsi un fond commun,
> ce continuum à trois dimensions qui était le même pour toutes et qui
> ne se différenciait que par les figures qu'on y traçait ou quand on
> prétendait le mesurer. H. Poincaré, La Valeur de la sc.,1905, p. 59. ♦
> Continuum espace-temps. Continuum à quatre dimensions (les trois
> dimensions spatiales, plus le temps). Les concepts de continuum
> espace-temps, d'énergie, de force, de masse, d'entropie (Carrel,
> L'Homme, cet inconnu,1935, p. 36). Prononc. : [kɔ ̃tinɥ ɔm]. Pour la
> finale -um, cf. album. Étymol. et Hist. 1905 « ensemble d'éléments
> homogènes » supra ex.; 1935 continuum espace-temps (Carrel, loc.
> cit.). Mot lat. neutre de l'adj. continuus, v. continu; employé par
> les mathématiciens en b. lat. (ive.-ves.) opposé à discretus «
> distinct, séparé » (TLL s.v. continuus, 726, 52). Fréq. abs. littér. :
> 19.

Thus, I am wondering if indeed the (latin based) words continuum and (its plural form) continua cannot be used in French and in addition why one cannot do so.

Comment: As a scientific term it may not be translated word by word. Moreover, the discipline has alternative names, that may be more in use in french than in English: mechanics of continuum media may refer to elasticity theory or fluid mechanics/hydrodynamics. (Wikipedia supports your translation though .)

Comment: @RogerVadim Wikipedia also has [Mécanique des milieux continus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9canique_des_milieux_continus)  for "Continuum mechanics" !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term exists indeed, but I never heard it/used it outside *continuum espace temps* (and now I'm "back to the future" :p).

I would would go with your colleagues suggestion:

> Mécanique des milieux continus

(I suppose there are several such domains, and not just one).

Answer (score 4):

The term "continuum" is perfectly valid. Aside from the "continuum espace-temps", which designates the four-dimensional space in which physics are set, there is the much less scientific expression "***sur un continuum*** allant de ... à ...", which in English would translate as "*on a spectrum from ... to ...*".

I have never heard the plural form *continua* used.

As for the sentence that you were trying to translate originally, the correct translation is indeed **mécanique des milieux continus**. That's an expression that maps directly to the concept of *continuum mechanics* in English and is used e.g. to describe a course in a curriculum.

Similarly *Special relativity* does not translate to *"*relativité spéciale*" but to **relativité restreinte** ("*restricted*").

Answer (score 3):

*Continuum* is a false friend.

In all the fields that I'm familiar with in modern mathematics, computer science and physics, the French word “*continuum*” is not used. It's a rather old-fashioned word and mostly used as a non-technical term in the sense of “spectrum”: “*il y a un continuum de valeurs possibles*” = “there is a spectrum of possible values” (i.e. between two possible values, there is always another possible value).

I'm not specifically familiar with the expression “[continuum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics)” but I have no reason to doubt the title of the corresponding page in French Wikipedia: “*[mécanique des milieux continus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9canique_des_milieux_continus)*”.

In mathematics and computer science we use “*continu*” as a noun: “*le discret*” is opposed to “*le continu*”. For example “[cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum)” is “*cardinal du continu*” or (maybe a little old-fashioned these days) “*[puissance du continu](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puissance_du_continu)*”.

Comment: Neither a false friend nor a non-technical term [when used in linguistics](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_linguistique) though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the French wikipedia lemma for "continuum"

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum

giving as an alternative

> Le continuum mécanique
>
> Sciences et technologies - Physique
>
> Le continuum mécanique, une branche
> de la physique

I don't see anything faulty with continuum mécanique (grammatically speaking) other than its unknown usage. Of course it may sound awkward to French natives.
Obviously, Wikipedia is not panacea.

Comment: Given the standard order of French nouns and adjectives, wouldn't *le continuum mécanique* be *the mechanical continuum* and not *continuum mechanics*?

Comment: Your link for "Le continuum mécanique"  points to a page called **Mécanique des milieux continus**, "continuum" is only used on the "homonymie" page.